# matlab allocating upper triangular sparse matrix before loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, memory-management, sparse-matrix

How do I allocate a sparse matrix where upper triangular portion is non-zero and the lower triangular portion is zeros? I'm currently looking at the spalloc() function

```
U = [0.046805;0.047415;0.048025;0.046805;0.047415;0.048025]; % small example here this can be very large!
V = [-0.000305;-0.000305;-0.000305;-0.000935;-0.000935;-0.000935]; % small example here this can be very large!
N = length(U);
A=zeros(N); % allocate upper triangular diagonal sparse matrix here
B=zeros(N); % allocate upper triangular diagonal sparse matrix here
for i=1:N-1
    for j=i+1:N
        A(i,j)=4*U(i)*U(j)/((U(i)+U(j)).^2+(V(i)-V(j)).^2);
        B(i,j) = sqrt((U(i)*U(j))/(A(i,j)));
    end
end
% Later do some maths with the non-zeros
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking since you say you're planning to use `spalloc`. The arguments are pretty well explained in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spalloc.html).

Comment: I wasn't fixated on using THAT particular function in my original post.  I was querying if I was looking at the most applicable function to my particular problem? Sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes the function is well documented as you say. I can't work out how to use that function to assign non-zeros to the upper half of the matrix all in one step.

Comment: Ah, the I misunderstood as well. I thought you were simply trying to preallocate the memory, not actually populate the values.

Comment: I think your only options are to use `spalloc` with `nzmax = (N^2 - N)/2`, or pre-generate vectors for the indices and values and use `sparse(i, j, v)`. I don't have access to Matlab right now to verify, but it seems to me that if you're going to generate the values anyway, `spalloc` would not be any slower than `sparse` and may be faster.

Comment: @beaker ok thanks! I'll give it a go. One thing I must avoid is to preallocate a matrix normally than use sparse otherwise would be pointless then..

Answer (score 0):

Does the following answer your question?

```
clear all;

m = ones(5);

for r = 1:size(m,1)
    for c = 1:size(m,2)
        if c<r
            m(r,c) = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: not actually I'm looking to allocate a sparse matrix before looping for speed and memory efficiency. The matrix I'm implementing can be very large ranging from N: 1x1<=N<=20kx20k+ !

Comment: That is out of my skills then. If you explain it clearly in the post, you may get attention of experts on the topic then.